# Label is showing under checkbox and both should be center aligned

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox

I am confused. I got this form, jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rx90f38u/1/

It has the styling in there and I can't work out why "remember" me shows under the checkbox.

The checkbox and label should be on same line and centered.

CSS:

```
.bbp-login-form input[type=text], .bbp-login-form input[type=password], .bbp-login-form select {
  width: 100% !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
  -webkit-border-radius:4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
}

.bbp-login-form label {
    text-align:left;
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<h2 class="widgettitle">Support Forums</h2>
<form action="https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/wp-login.php" class="bbp-login-form" method="post">
    <fieldset>
    <div class="bbp-username">
        <label for="user_login">Username: </label>
        <input id="user_login" name="log" size="20" tabindex="103" type="text" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="bbp-password">
        <label for="user_pass">Password: </label>
        <input id="user_pass" name="pwd" size="20" tabindex="104" type="password" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="bbp-remember-me">
        <input id="rememberme" name="rememberme" tabindex="105" type="checkbox" value="forever">
        <label for="rememberme">Remember Me</label> </div>
    </fieldset></form>

</body>
```

If I add this CSS then I get **Remember Me** center:

```
.bbp-login-form .bbp-remember-me label {
    text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}
```

But even if I reduce the width still a problem.

Comment: Just using flex. something like this: `.bbp-remember-me{ display:flex;}`

Comment: Your lables have `width: 100%`. How can you fit both elements on a single row when one takes up the entire width?

Comment: @Turnip Doesn't seem to change it.

Comment: You are using `!important` here `width: 100% !important` so `width: 50%;` will be ignored. This works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/6v2u7cj4/

Comment: @Turnip That works. Thanks. But how do we make sure then that the box and text are vertically aligned too centrally?

Comment: @Turnip, also, please put your fiddle and comments in an answer for me. It is just the vertical alignment now (if it is possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.bbp-login-form .bbp-remember-me label {
        text-align: left;
        width: auto !important;
        vertical-align: initial;
    }
```

Comment: I have accepted this answer because the key was setting the label `width: auto;`. As provided in the comments to my question with a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
.bbp-login-form label {
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block !important;
}

.bbp-remember-me{
   text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jdfkbvrt/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flexbox to do the job .

```
.bbp-remember-me{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xh831fnd/1/